# Bootstrap4: card header and navigation on one row

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, navigation

In Boostrap 4, how can we position some nav and text within a Card Header to display on a single row?

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
  Heading
    <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Nav 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Nav 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Nav 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    ...      
  </div>
</div>
```

The HTML markup above renders the navigation onto a new line below the Heading:

[image: Incorrectly formatted Card Heading]

The heading should be left-aligned, with the nav pushed to the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the heading as a list item also(`<li>`) - like in the code below...

```css
li {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        Heading
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Nav 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Nav 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Nav 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    WHATEVER... really...
  </div>
</div>
```